# Css and Javascript not working in component Angular 6

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I have two different templates (different css and javascript). One for personal page and one for todolist. I try add css and into component. But this not working and i move css and javascript to index.html then it working. However, At the same time, my website inherits two kinds css.

[image]

I want to import javascript or css in local component. How to do this? 
 Thanks, 
 Cheer

Comment: Javascript (typescript) code you put in the constructor of the `component.ts` class. And CSS you link to it in the `@Component({ ... })` decorator of the same class with the `styleUrls` property. Can you share your class code?

Comment: You have to configure the CLI to build two projects. Then each project has its own list of assets.

Comment: What kind of encapsulation do you have in that component? (ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: You may need to add in your angular.json(`styles`)  files if you are using angular-cli. it will work in all your component. no need to add in all your component or index.html. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your individual component's css file path in styleUrls property of [@Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) decorator.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-personal-page',
    templateUrl: './personal-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./personal-page.component.css'],
})
```

It would implement 'personal-page.component.css' file's style only on personal-page component.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the code with in component along with the folder structure it would be great.

Basically check in `@Component` decorative whether `stylesUrl` property having the proper URL of your CSS file.